# innerHTML добавление значения

Tags: javascript

Есть 3 переменных. b1, b2, b3. Как вывести их значения в цикле, что бы буква a названия переменной была постоянной, а цифры изменялись.

> b + i

Спасибо.

```
 let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');

 let b1 = 'text 1';
 let b2 = 'text 2';
 let b3 = 'text 3';

 for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  box1.appendChild(document.createElement('h3')).innerHTML = b + i;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `eval()`

```js
let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');

let b1 = 'text 1';
let b2 = 'text 2';
let b3 = 'text 3';

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  box1.appendChild(document.createElement('h3')).innerHTML = eval('b' + i);
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Но лучше использовать массивы

```js
let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');

let b = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3'];

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  box1.appendChild(document.createElement('h3')).innerHTML = b[i];
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

или объекты

```js
let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');

let obj = {
  b1: 'text 1',
  b2: 'text 2',
  b3: 'text 3'
};

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  box1.appendChild(document.createElement('h3')).innerHTML = obj['b' + i];
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте Anton Shchyrov! Большое Вам спасибо! Метод eval() был нужен!

Comment: Очень плохая эта функция. Лучше не использовать ее никогда. А то можно такого получить...

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно переменные с текстами поместить как свойства объекта (можно поместить их в массив и обращаться по индексам в массиве):

```js
let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');

let texts = {
  b1: 'text 1',
  b2: 'text 2',
  b3: 'text 3'
};


for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  box1.appendChild(document.createElement('h3')).innerHTML = texts['b' + i];
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Или, как вариант заменить `let` на `var`, и вызывать из глобального window (но, как мне кажется, это не самый лучший вариант):

```js
let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');

var b1 = 'text 1';
var b2 = 'text 2';
var b3 = 'text 3';

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  box1.appendChild(document.createElement('h3')).innerHTML = window['b' + i];
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте Sergey Glazirin! Большое Вам спасибо!